# Convert decimal string IP mask to unsigned int with trailing zeros

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitmask

I get a mask as a string that I retrieve using `strtol` and `strtok` and that I want to save in an `unsigned int x`, trail with zeros, and `&` it with an IP represented also as `unsigned int` in order to keep the MSBs only (At the end I'm going to compare that IP with another).

My idea was to set all the bits of `x`, and then turn off all bits placed after the mask size:

```
#define IPV4_LENGTH 32

//subent is "123.34.45.66/31"

curr_IP->address = malloc(sizeof (struct in_addr));
token = strtok(subnet, "/");
inet_aton(token, curr_IP->address);
long mask  = strtol(strtok(NULL, "/"), NULL, 10);
curr_IP->x = -1;
for(long i=mask; i<=IPV4_LENGTH; i++){
    curr_IP->x &= ~(1U << i);
}
```

Example: if mask = 31, I want to end with 11111111111111111111111111111110 represented in `unsigned int` -> FFFFFFFE in HEX

P.S mask can't be 0

UPDATE:
Memory view after `curr_IP->x = -1;`

We can see it indeed sets up all the bits

[image]

Memory view after `curr_IP->x &= ~(1U << i);` when `i = 31`

expected `fffffffe`

[image]

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. Hard-code the "input", and include things like `IPV4_LENGTH`.

Comment: Also try to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. It helps if you split up more complex expressions into smaller and simpler expressions, assigned to temporary variables. For example, `curr_IP->x &= ~(1UL << i);` could be `unsigned long temp1 = 1UL << i; unsigned long temp2 = ~temp1; unsigned long temp3 = curr_IP->x & temp2; curr_IP->x = temp3;` Makes it easier to see and verify your expressions and calculations.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hope this is enough

Comment: My take on this: `curr_IP->x &= ~(1UL << i);` when `i = 32`. That means `curr_IP->x &= ~(1UL << 32UL)` and `(1UL << 32UL)` is 0 -> `curr_IP->x &= ~(0);` -> `curr_IP->x &= 0xFFFFFFFF;`

Comment: @MortenJensen I've changed `i=mask+1` to `i=mask` and updated the MEM view. I've also realized that I should use `int` instead of `long` because I need 32 bits only.

Comment: @RedYoel Remember that the size of types depends on compiler. For example, the Microsoft compiler still uses 32-bit `long`, even on 64-bit system.

Comment: @RedYoel `int` is signed and signed overflow is undefined behavior! So use an `unsigned int` or include `<stdint.h>` and use an `uint32_t` to get 32-bits nomatter the compiler

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You're right, I'll take Morten Jensen advice and use `uint32_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I choose a different approach; turning off the mask and then setting the relevant bits to 1.

```
long mask  = strtol(strtok(NULL, "/"), NULL, 10);
curr_IP->x = 0; //mask to 0
for(long i=IPV4_LENGTH - mask; i<IPV4_LENGTH; i++){
    curr_IP->x |= (1U << i); //Sets the ith bit of the mask
}
```

Edit: As Morten Jensen pointed, it is better not to mix signed and unsigned integers, so the corrected code looks like that:

```
unsigned long mask  = strtol(strtok(NULL, "/"), NULL, 10);
curr_IP->x = 0; //mask to 0
for(unsigned long i=IPV4_LENGTH - mask; i<IPV4_LENGTH; i++){
    curr_IP->x |= (1U << i); //Sets the ith bit of the mask
}
```

Also, I struggled with debugging the code myself because I used the **Memory view** without realizing that I should read it from **right to left**.

In picture #2, I thought that I got `fffffff7` when it was actually `7fffffff`

Comment: You kept with the signed integers I see :P?

Comment: @MortenJensen actually `curr_IP->x` is now a `uint32_t` as you suggested!

Comment: Yes but `mask` and `i` are signed. Why mix the signedness? I think an IPv4-address is always unsigned or..? I think that's something a compiler often warns against (mixing signedness)